# How to get global (company) group id in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, global

How to get the global (company) group id in Liferay without accessing `ThemeDisplay`?

P.S.: with `ThemeDisplay` it is simple: `themeDisplay.getCompanyGroupId()`.

Comment: If you don't have access to themeDisplay, you might want to give a few more details on where you actually need access to this information.

Comment: oh - according to the (accepted) answer it was even more simple than I though - or even more global. Guess my thoughts were too complex - good that you found it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you have only one `Company` in your portal:

```java
Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx(PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID));
long globalGroupId = company.getGroup().getGroupId();
```

Comment: `CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx(..)` where do you found this method! Great,  Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be more correct to use `CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByWebId()`

Answer (score 14):

Extending yellow's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056843/468763), you can find the `company` if you know some value of the Portal Instance (`Company`):

1. If you know the `webId` of the Portal Instance, can find `company` by:

   ```java
   String webId = "liferay.com"; // PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID)
   Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByWebId(webId);
   long globalGroupId = company.getGroup().getGroupId();
   ```
2. If you know the `mail-domain` of the Portal Instance, can find `company` by:

   ```java
   String mailDomain = "liferay.com";
   Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx(mailDomain);
   long globalGroupId = company.getGroup().getGroupId();
   ```
3. If you know the `virtual host` of the Portal Instance, can find `company` by:

   ```java
   String virtualHost = "localhost";
   Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByVirtualHost(virtualHost);
   long globalGroupId = company.getGroup().getGroupId();
   ```

<sub>There are also other useful methods available to explore in [`CompanyLocalServiceUtil`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/service/CompanyLocalServiceUtil.java), for those who are interested.</sub>

Thanks [Yellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832497/yellow) for the lead, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following :

```java
GroupLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyGroup(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId()).getGroupId();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this info for Document Library, you can use

```
public static long getDefaultCompanyId(){
        long companyId = 0;
        try{ companyId = getDefaultCompany().getCompanyId(); }
        catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e.getClass() + " " +e.getMessage()); }
       return companyId;
}

public static long getDefaultGroupId (){

    long companyId = getDefaultCompanyId();
    long globalGroupId = 0L;

    Group group = null;
    try {
        group = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(companyId, "Guest");
    } catch (PortalException | SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return globalGroupId;
    }
     globalGroupId = group.getGroupId();


    return globalGroupId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking this up in 2023:

Just use: `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId()`